# Comparar 2 resultados SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

Necesito saber si existe alguna función o de que manera puedo comparar 2 resultados SQL...
Son 2 consultas a la misma tabla que devuelven la misma estructura de datos.
En si estoy tratando de comparar las direcciones existentes de un cliente vs la que se le intenta ingresar.

Comment: qué has intentado hasta ahora y errores que te da?

Comment: Hola Nico, intenta aportar código realizado ti y ser algo mas específico en la pregunta, esto va a facilitar encontrar una respuesta infinitamente mas rápido. Para esta finalidad te recomiendo comprobar este enlace con muy buenos consejos [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la palabra clave EXCEPT.

```
SELECT <CONSULTA1>
EXCEPT  
SELECT <CONSULTA2>
```

Te devolverá los registros diferentes. Es decir, si son iguales los 2 resultados sql, no devolveria nada.

Comment: Hay que hacer la consulta en ambos sentidos para verificar que la consulta 2 no tenga filas que no existan en la consulta1. También hay que verificar conteos para asegurarse de no tener duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma equivalente a la respuesta de Aritz agnóstica al servidor SQL donde se ejecute, sería:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2
FROM  tabla
WHERE filtro_a
      AND (col_1, col_2) NOT IN (
         SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 
         FROM tabla 
         WHERE filtro_b
      )
```

donde `filtro_a` y `filtro_b` serían dos expresiones que definirían el resultado de las dos consultas a la misma tabla.